# How to add to an existing list - got Unsupported operation: Cannot add to an unmodifiable list

Tags: flutter

I am trying to add to a `List` which results in `Unsupported operation: Cannot add to an unmodifiable list`

But message list is not final, why can't I add Items to it?

```
class Chat {
  final String uuid;
  final User receiverUser;
  List<Message> messages;

  Chat({this.uuid, this.receiverUser, this.messages = const []});   
}
```

---

In my provider I have a send message method

```
  void send(String receiverUUID) async {
    Message message = Message(
        message: messageController.text,
        receiverUUID: receiverUUID,
        timestamp: DateTime.now());

    await _messageApi.send(message);

    Chat chat = await _findOrCreate(receiverUUID);    
    /// FIXME Unhandled Exception: Unsupported operation: Cannot add to an unmodifiable list
    chat.messages.add(message);

    notifyListeners();
  }
```

Answer (score 36, accepted):

*Note: if `messages` was final you could still add items to that list. The problem is that `messages` is being assigned to the default `const[]` in your constructor.*

Instead of:

```dart
chat.messages.add(message);
```

Try this:

```dart
chat.messages = [...chat.messages, message];
```

`...` is the [Spread Operator](https://dart.dev/guides/language/language-tour#spread-operator). This line will create a new list with `message` at the end.

You could also use `List.from()` combined with `..`:

```dart
chat.messages = List.from(chat.messages)..add(message);
```

Here, `..` is the [Cascade Notation](https://dart.dev/guides/language/language-tour#cascade-notation). It will add `message` to the new list but the list will be returned instead of the result of the `add` method (that would be void).

You could also initialize the `messages` with a non const []:

```dart
class Chat {
  final String uuid;
  final User receiverUser;
  List<Message> messages;

  Chat({this.uuid, this.receiverUser, List<Messages>? messages})
    : messages = messages ?? [];   
}
```

Comment: Thank you it worked :) Is there a way to initialize message with empty list without using const?

Comment: @combi35 in new dart (The default value of an optional parameter must be constant.) , ref: https://dart.dev/tools/diagnostic-messages?utm_source=dartdev&utm_medium=redir&utm_id=diagcode&utm_content=non_constant_default_value#non_constant_default_value