Flutter/Dart: Unsupported operation: Cannot add to an unmodifiable list
I have a modifiable list (I did not set the list to have a fixed size) but run into this error

Unsupported operation: Cannot add to an unmodifiable list

The source code that throws this error is:
for (int i = 0; i < globals.produkte.length; i++){
   globals.produkte[i].kategorienBool.add(false);
}

kategorienbool is a List of bool with no fixed size.
This is how kategorienBool is defined in my class Produkte:
List<bool> kategorienBool;
Produkt({
    required this.zutat,
    required this.menge,
    this.mhd,
    this.verfaelltInXTagen,
    this.einheit = "g",
    this.anlage,
    this.kategorien = const ["keine"],
    this.kategorienBool = const [false],
    this.offen = false,
    this.color = const Color.fromRGBO(0, 0, 0, 1)
  });

So

My list is not set to a fixed size and
all related Flutter pages in my app are build with a StatefulWidget (which a few articles recommended as cause for this issue)

These two cover what I found on the internet about this problem so far, but both did not solve my problem.
Can someone give me a hint what I might be doing wrong/what I might also take into consideration?

This question is similar to: flutter : Unsupported operation: Cannot add to an unmodifiable list. If you believe it’s different, please edit the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.

Its likely not different but the recommendations in that article did not help me. Can I "wake up" that thread somehow?

You could do some of the suggested actions here: https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/48579 - but if the recommendations did not help, it probably means your situation is different from theirs, perhaps you could look into this and modify your question to make it more obvious what specifically is different so others may be able to help more :)

I edited my post to outline that I already tried what can be found in the articles you linked but did not solve my problem.

You initialized the list with const.  Maybe don't do that, since the list is not supposed to have a constant value?  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66550202/how-to-add-to-an-existing-list-got-unsupported-operation-cannot-add-to-an-unm

You're getting the error because you're initializing the list kategorienBool  as a constant List.
// ...
    this.kategorienBool = const [false],
// ...

And later on, you're trying to add items to the same list - which in turn throws the exception.
What I would do in this situation is use something like this:
class SomeClass {
  List<bool> myList;

  SomeClass({
    List<bool>? myList,
  }) : myList = myList ?? [false];
}

void main() {
  var ob = SomeClass();
  ob.myList.add(true); // <- works fine
}

Hope this helps!
